# mac terminal, auto close after execution is complete but only if there was no error

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

I am running a lot of CLI tools lately and it started to annoy me that every time i run some command group via `.command` file i have to manually close terminal window. So i came up with this stuff:

```
__YOUR__CODE__TO__BE__EXECUTED

echo -n -e "\033]0;Make\007"
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to close (every window whose name contains "Make")' &
exit
```

lets say this is my `make.command` file. The problem is that window is closed regardless of the result of the `__YOUR__CODE__TO__BE__EXECUTED` section. So if i for example run a grunt task or server file upload, i dont really know if it worked or not, does anyone have a suggestion how to adapt the code to make it close terminal but only if there was no error in console?

Answer (score 0):

try command

```
sleep 10 #pause for 10 seconds
```

Comment: although it can be used for like "last resort", it seems like half measure, maybe it can be adjusted so it actually reads the response and somehow verify if its error or not